# Django : foreign key, set and related_name

Tags: django

I have a problem when I want add a model instance to the database :

The model :

```
class M(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_send = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,related_name="+")

    class Meta :
        abstract = True

class MP(M):
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False)
```

When I add an instance :

```
 def the_view(request) :
     ...
     MP.objects.create(text="aaaah",sender=request.user,receipt=User_Finded_Before)

    ...
```

Nothing errors.

BUT when I want find all MP instance of a sender (Model User), I find nothing :

```
def view2(request) :
    u = request.user
    u.mp_set.all()
    ...
```

"u.mp_set.all()" return nothing, why ?

Comment: Did you check that the object is being created?

Comment: Yes, it's created.. I find it when I write MP.objects.all()

Comment: Give http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html a try. You can inspect your models easily with it. Maybe you have a name clash somewhere.